# Android - Latitude Longitude information for image

Tags: android, android-image

I am trying to retrieve latitude and longitude information of an image. Here is the code I have:

```
String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LATITUDE,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LONGITUDE,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN
        };

  final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC";

  Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns,
                null,
                null,
                orderBy
        );

   int count = cursor.getCount();
   Double latitude, longitude;
   String filePath;
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LATITUDE));
            longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LONGITUDE));
            filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
            Log.i("Image>>",filePath);
            Log.i("Latitude>>", latitude+"");
            Log.i("Longitude>>",longitude+"");

        }
```

But latitude and longitude are always 0.0. I am using Android SDK 16. Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did the image come from? Was it taken by the device's camera?

Comment: Yes. I also have other images. I am trying to scan all image files in the device.

Comment: Was geotagging enabled on the phone when these images were clicked?

Comment: How do I explicitly enable geo tagging? I switched on GPS and clicked an image. I still get the same results

Answer (score 2):

My bad. I enabled location on camera before taking a snap and this returns the correct location.!